# Retroactively run a process on existing records meeting criteria

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, processbuilder

I am trying to retroactively run a process on records that meet certain criteria on my organization.

I have a csv report of the records and tried updating thru Data loader so they can meet the required criteria. However even when trying to update the records to meet criteria on the data loader it fails to update the records because cant trigger the flow.

Does anyone has a clue why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to decrease the batch limit for Dataloader try with 1 and see if it works, then the problem is with bulk-ification

Comment: @mustafa it worked with just one, how is this solved?